# Height toggle animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm just preparing some simple demo for work and I'm stuck with the height toggle animation with jQuery.

```
$('a.content-toggle').click(function() {
    var toggleHeight = $("#panel_1").height() == 500 ? "200px" : "500px";
    $("#panel_1").animate({ height: toggleHeight }); 
});
```

I understand `toggle` function is deprecated so I'm using `click` to simulate the toggle.

I can get the panel to grow to 500px if I set 200px in CSS but shrinking back to 200px is not working.

This is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/oumaqgft/16/) It's `...` in the first panel that triggers toggle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the [box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), which is by default [content-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Values) so the height property will exclude the padding and border, so `toggleHeight` will return 466 not 500

```
var toggleHeight = $("#panel_1").outerHeight() == 500 ? "200px" : "500px";
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5hw9tjeg/)